# Soft memory limit for AWS ECS task defined by docker-compose.yaml

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, docker-compose, amazon-ecs

Amazon provides `ecs-cli compose` command which can set up task definition from docker-compose.yaml

But I am not able to declare memory limits (especially soft one) for such task. Deploy option is not supported.

```
Skipping unsupported YAML option for service...  option name=deploy
```

Is there way how to achieve this with compose? Or is using compose bad idea and it's better to use native task definitions.

**update**
My compose file was requested, here is it

```
version: '3'

services:
  worker:
    image: 880289074637.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/negative-keywords:latest
    env_file: .env
    command: ["celery", "-A", "negmatch", "worker", "-l", "info"]
    deploy:
      resources:
        limits:
          cpus: '0.50'
          memory: 256M
        reservations:
          cpus: '0.25'
          memory: 128M
  web:
    image: 880289074637.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/negative-keywords:latest
    env_file: .env
    ports:
      - "80:8000"
    depends_on:
      - "worker"
    deploy:
      resources:
        limits:
          cpus: '0.50'
          memory: 256M
        reservations:
          cpus: '0.25'
          memory: 128M
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use v2 of docker compose to set the values.

As of today, according [docker docs](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#resources), `deploy` is meant for swarm mode deployment only.

> Looking for options to set resources on non swarm mode containers?
>
> The options described here are specific to the **deploy** key and swarm
>   mode. If you want to set resource constraints on non swarm
>   deployments, use [Compose file format version 2 CPU, memory, and other
>   resource options](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v2/#cpu-and-other-resources). If you have further questions, refer to the
>   discussion on the GitHub issue [docker/compose/4513](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/4513).

More info on using v2 vs v3.
https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/4513#issuecomment-377311337

Here is sample docker-compose(v2) which sets the soft and hard memory limits on container definition of task. `mem_limit` is hard limit and `mem_reservation` is soft limit.

Command -

```
ecs-cli compose --project-name nginx --file docker-compose.yaml create
```

Compose File -

```
version: '2'
services:
  nginx:
    image: "nginx:latest"
    mem_limit: 512m
    mem_reservation: 128m
    cpu_shares: 0
    ports:
      - 80
```

[image]

Comment: I wrote docker-compose version 3 (as I understand from docs in version 3 mem limits should be declared as deploy/resources....) 

Using version 2  could be option.

Comment: @farincz can you share your version 3 sample?. It might be possible, ecs-cli is not compatible with latest version of docker compose. we can check.

Comment: sure, I've just append it to question

Comment: @farincz check my updated answer. You might want to go with v2 for now.